# golang linter always complains

Tags: go, static-analysis, golangci-lint

Q: How do I resolve this madness between the `ireturn` and `nolintlint` linters?

Details:

I have a Golang function with this signature

```
func NewClientCredentialsTokenSource(
    issuer string,
    clientId string,
    clientSecret string,
    scope []string,
) (oauth2.TokenSource, error) {
```

When I run golangci-lint v1.43.0 it reports

```
golangci-lint run
oidc/token_utils.go:19:1: NewClientCredentialsTokenSource returns interface (golang.org/x/oauth2.TokenSource) (ireturn)
func NewClientCredentialsTokenSource(
```

Since the function has only two return params it is easy to deduce it is complaining about `oauth2.TokenSource` and not `error`.

The downstream function called by `NewClientCredentialsTokenSource` returns an instance of `oauth2.TokenSource` so I don't have a concrete type to return. I have no choice but to return the `oauth2.TokenSource` interface.

So I add a lint exception to the function like this:

```
//nolint:ireturn
func NewClientCredentialsTokenSource(
    issuer string,
    clientId string,
    clientSecret string,
    scope []string,
) (oauth2.TokenSource, error) {
```

You'd think that should fix it but no! Now there's a new lint issue is reported:

```
golangci-lint run
oidc/token_utils.go:19:1: directive `//nolint:ireturn` is unused for linter "ireturn" (nolintlint)
//nolint:ireturn
```

So now I'm chasing my tail. `ireturn` complains I am returning an interface. I add an exception for that function only to have `nolintlint` complain I have an exception that doesn't apply.

What's a guy to do?

Comment: "What's a guy to do?" I would just disable `nolintlint`. That seems excessive.

Comment: This wasn't error, but sideeffect of `/nolint` checking within `ireturn` itself, rather then in `golangci-lint`. This is going to be fixed in next version (wating just for go version update), then patch will be deployed to `golangci-lint`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried adding the allow rule as suggested by Nico Huysamen but that opened a can of worms. In the end I still want to believe in the `ireturn` linter and don't want to disable it yet. I figure the cleanest way to resolve this issue is to add an exception for both linters, `ireturn` and `nolintlint` as shown here:

```
//nolint:nolintlint,ireturn
func NewClientCredentialsTokenSource(
    issuer string,
    clientId string,
    clientSecret string,
    scope []string,
) (oauth2.TokenSource, error) {
```

**Update 5/25/2022:**

Perhaps a better solution is shown below. For some reason the `ireturn` exception has to go *inside* the function signature.

```
func NewPasswordGrantTokenSource( //nolint:ireturn
    issuer string,
    clientId string,
    clientSecret string,
    username string,
    password string,
    scope []string,
) (oauth2.TokenSource, error) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can allow this in `.golangci.yml` as mentioned above but as it replaces the [standard defaults](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/blob/master/.golangci.reference.yml#L1061), you need to include them too so you would need:

```yaml
  ireturn:
    # ireturn allows using `allow` and `reject` settings at the same time.
    # Both settings are lists of the keywords and regular expressions matched to interface or package names.
    # keywords:
    # - `empty` for `interface{}`
    # - `error` for errors
    # - `stdlib` for standard library
    # - `anon` for anonymous interfaces

    # By default, it allows using errors, empty interfaces, anonymous interfaces,
    # and interfaces provided by the standard library.
    allow:
      - anon
      - error
      - empty
      - stdlib
      # You can specify idiomatic endings for interface
      - (or|er)$
      # Your custom interfaces go here:
      - golang.org/x/oauth2.TokenSource
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the interface to `ireturn`'s list of allowed interfaces.

```bash
ireturn --allow="golang.org/x/oauth2.TokenSource"
```

or via the `linter-settings` section in `.golangci.yml`

```yaml
linters-settings:
  ireturn:
    allow:
      - golang.org/x/oauth2.TokenSource
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it opened a can of worms. After adding that one interface as an exception in .golangci.yml the linter then complained about every method/function that returned `error` so I added an exception for `error`. Then it complained about every function that returns `net/http.Handler` (something it didn't previously do.) After that came the ultimate insult, it complained about functions that return `interface{}` and I couldn't find a way to add an exception for `interface{}` (`interface{}` has been used in limited cases due to the lack of generics in Go 1.17.3.)

Comment: Ouch. Maybe then just disable ‘ireturn’ 